# What's the effect of find_package(catkin components ...)?

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that with catkin in Groovy,

```
find_package(catkin COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs)
```

is equivalent to

```
find_package(catkin)
find_package(roscpp)
find_package(std_msgs)
```

Is there any difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48133/what%27s-the-effect-of-find_package(catkin-components-...)?/) by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7848 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-04-21**:
Follow up question: How does CMake know to look for the .cmake config files in the /opt/ros/ directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I understand they are equivalent.

The only difference is that `find_package(catkin COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs)` will consolidate all of the COMPONENTS into the catkin_* CMake variables, for instance catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS will contain roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS and std_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-11-13**:
I could have checked the docs: http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though it may be obvious from William's response, using the first method is more convenient and actually recommended. the consequence of using the latter is that all of the CMake functions/macros that utilize environment variables generated by find_package() have to have the corresponding variable listed as an argument. For C++ code, this particularly effects include_directories() and target_link_libraries(). Example:

Instead of :

```
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(foo ...)
target_link_libraries(foo ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

You would have:

```
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${std_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(foo ...)
target_link_libraries(foo ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${roscpp_LIBRARIES} ${std_msgs_LIBRARIES})
```

**So save yourself effort and always find catkin packages as components of catkin!**

---

Originally posted by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) with karma: 1209 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7